# How to properly override JacksonAnnotationIntrospector._findAnnotation to replace an annotation of the element

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, annotations

I am trying to create some classes serializable by Jackson. I want to annotate some elements with standard Jackson annotation (let's consider `JsonIgnore` for this example) but I want them to have effect only in my specific mapper.

So I decided to create my own annotations like standard ones (e. g. MyJsonIgnore) and process them only in an annotation introspector used by my mapper. I've found overridable method `_findAnnotation`. Javadoc says the following:

```
...overridable that sub-classes may, if they choose to, 
mangle actual access block access ("hide" annotations) 
or perhaps change it.
```

I've found a way to block some annotations (however it involves overriding `_hasAnnotation`, not `_findAnnotation`) but I am completely stuck with changing annotations.

Here is some minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```
object Mappers {
    /**
     * Same as JsonIgnore but mapper-specific
     */
    annotation class MyJsonIgnore(val value: Boolean = true)

    private class MyIntrospector : JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        override fun <A : Annotation> _findAnnotation(
            annotated: Annotated,
            annoClass: Class<A>
        ): A {
            if (annoClass == JsonIgnore::class.java && _hasAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore::class.java)) {
                val mji = _findAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore::class.java)
                return JsonIgnore(mji.value) // Does not compile, type mismatch
                // return JsonIgnore(mji.value) as A // Does not compile, annotation class cannot be instantiated, same as Java, see below
            }
            return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass)
        }
    }

    fun myMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(MyIntrospector())
    }
}
```

I also cannot do it with Java:

```java
public class Mappers {
    /**
     * Same as JsonIgnore but mapper-specific
     */
    public @interface MyJsonIgnore {
        boolean value() default true;
    }

    private static class MyIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
        @Override
        protected <A extends Annotation> A _findAnnotation(Annotated annotated,
                                                           Class<A> annoClass) {
            if (annoClass == JsonIgnore.class && _hasAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore.class)) {
                MyJsonIgnore mji = _findAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore.class);
                return new JsonIgnore(mji.value()); // Does not compile, JsonIgnore is abstract
            }
            return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass);
        }
    }

    static ObjectMapper myMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper().setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyIntrospector())
    }
}
```

So what is the supposed way to change annotations by overriding this method? Is there any? Is my approach right or should I do it other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you can't instantiate the annotation class. There is one solution though: you could store [one annotation as a member of another annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) like this:

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME) // don't forget 
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)         // these annotations
annotation class MyJsonIgnore(val value: Boolean = true, val jsonIgnore: JsonIgnore = JsonIgnore())
```

So `MyJsonIgnore` will have an instantiated `JsonIgnore` inside. And then you can use it in your `AnnotationIntrospector`:

```
private class MyIntrospector : JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
    override fun <A : Annotation> _findAnnotation(
            annotated: Annotated,
            annoClass: Class<A>
    ): A? {
        if (annoClass == JsonIgnore::class.java && _hasAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore::class.java)) {
            val mji = _findAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore::class.java)
            if (mji?.value == true) {
                return mji.jsonIgnore as A // this cast should be safe because we have checked
                                           // the annotation class
            }
        }
        return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass)
    }
}
```

I've tested this with the following class

```
class Test {
    @MyJsonIgnore
    val ignoreMe = "IGNORE"
    val field = "NOT IGNORE"
}
```

and method

```
fun main() {
    println(Mappers.myMapper().writeValueAsString(Test()))
    println(ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Test()))
}
```

and the output was

```
{"field":"NOT IGNORE"}
{"ignoreMe":"IGNORE","field":"NOT IGNORE"}
```

Answer (score 2):

So here are my further thoughts. Kirill Simonov's answer is right and typesafe (an alternative would be to create an annotation instance using Kotlin reflection but it is not typesafe).

Here are some problems with my original code and thoughts about the original approach:

1. **You should consistently override `_hasAnnotation` and `_getAnnotation`**

You cannot be sure that `_getAnnotation` will be called after `_hasAnnotation` check. You cannot be sure which of them will be used to check your replaced annotation (`@JsonIgnore` in my case) without looking into `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` code. It seems that overriding them consistently would be a good practice. So we should also add the following override to our class if we want to use this approach:

```
override fun <A : Annotation> _hasAnnotation(
    annotated: Annotated,
    annoClass: Class<A>
): Boolean {
    if (annoClass == JsonIgnore::class.java && _hasAnnotation(annotated, MyJsonIgnore::class.java)) {
        return true
    }
    return super._hasAnnotation(annotated, annoClass)
}
```

2. **`_getAnnotation` return type should be nullable**

This was correctly fixed by Kirill but was not explicitly pointed out. `_getAnnotation` can and will return null sometimes.

3. **You (probably) cannot have one magic `MyConditional` annotation.**

Kirill's answer may encourage you to create something like a conditional annotation for all the jackson annotation which could be used as follows:

```
@MyConditional([
    JsonIgnore, JsonProperty("propertyName")
])
```

You just cannot have polymorphic annotation parameter. You would have to create `My*` for every Jackson annotation you need and for annotation with parameters it's not as neat as with `@MyJsonIgnore`.

<s>You can try to make a repeatable annotation which would be applied like below and instantiated using reflection.</s>

```
@MyConditional(
    clazz = JsonProperty::class.java,
    args = [
        // Ah, you probably cannot have an array of any possible args here, forget it.
    ]
)
```

4. **`_hasAnnotation` and `_getAnnotation` are not the only ways which `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` uses to get or check for annotations**

After using similar approach to create conditional `@JsonProperty` annotation I've noticed that it does not work for enum elements. After some debugging I found out that `findEnumValues` method uses `java.lang.reflect.Field::getAnnotation` directly (due to "various reasons" mentioned in deprecated `findEnumValue`). If you want your conditional annotation to work you should override (at least) `findEnumValues`.

5. **Be careful with `ObjectMapper::setAnnotationIntrospector`**

Well, its Javadoc explicitly says it: be careful. It replaces the whole annotation introspector of your mapper removing all the added (chained) by modules Introspectors. It did not appear in my code in the question (it was for the sake of creating minimal example) but actually I've accidentally broke deserialization with `KotlinModule`. You may want to consider implementing JacksonModule and appending your introspector to existing ones.

6. **Consider another approach: implementing functionality-specific methods in `NopAnnotationIntrospector`.**

At the end I ended up with this approach (mostly because of 4.). I needed to override `findEnumValues` and `hasIgnoreMarker` and it was enough for me. It involved a bit of copy-paste code from `JacksonAnnotationMapper` but unless you have to make a lot of the annotation conditional it might work (in any case implementing it involves a lot of boilerplate code). This way it's likely that you really want to chain this introspector, not to `set` it.