# Swap Jackson custom serializer / deserializer during runtime

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson-databind

**I have the following system:**

[image]

- I am sending `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`s from spring controllers to my client and vice versa.
- I also have an export/import feature of my to-be-serialized classes. The JSON File is created by using an `ObjectMapper` and utilizing the `writeValueAsString` and `readValue` methods. I am reading from and writing into the json file.
- Both of those serialization paths currently utilize the same serializers/deserializers.

I use the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations to define custom serialization for some of my objects.
I want to serialize those objects differently for export/import.

So I want to swap the serializer / deserializer for the export/import task. Something like this:

[image]

If I understand the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/) correctly, those two annotations only allow one `using` class. But I want to register multiple serializers/deserializers and use them based on some conditional logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is my solution**

It's not pretty but does its job.

I left my old jackson config untouched, so the client<->server serialization stays the same.
I then added this custom ObjectMapper to take care of my server<->file.

My custom ObjectMapper does the following things:

1. It registers a new custom JacksonAnnotationIntrospector, which I configured to ignore certain annotations. I also configured it to use my selfmade annotation `@TransferJsonTypeInfo` whenever a property has both the `@TransferJsonTypeInfo` as well as the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation.
2. I registered my `CustomerFileSerializer` and `CustomerFileDeserializer` for this ObjectMapper.

```
@Service
public class ImportExportMapper {

    protected final ObjectMapper customObjectMapper;

    private static final JacksonAnnotationIntrospector IGNORE_JSON_ANNOTATIONS_AND_USE_TRANSFERJSONTYPEINFO = BuildImportExportJacksonAnnotationIntrospector();

    public ImportExportMapper(){
        customObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        // emulate the default settings as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper
        customObjectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        customObjectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Customer.class, new CustomerFileSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Customer.class, new CustomerFileDeserializer());

        customObjectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(IGNORE_JSON_ANNOTATIONS_AND_USE_TRANSFERJSONTYPEINFO);

        customObjectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    public String writeValueAsString(Object data) {
        try {
            return customObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public ObjectTransferData readValue(String fileContent, Class clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return customObjectMapper.readValue(fileContent, clazz);
    }

    private static JacksonAnnotationIntrospector BuildImportExportJacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        return new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {

            @Override
            protected <A extends Annotation> A _findAnnotation(final Annotated annotated, final Class<A> annoClass) {
                if (annoClass == JsonTypeInfo.class && _hasAnnotation(annotated, FileJsonTypeInfo.class)) {
                    FileJsonTypeInfo fileJsonTypeInfo = _findAnnotation(annotated, TransferJsonTypeInfo.class);
                    if(fileJsonTypeInfo != null && fileJsonTypeInfo.jsonTypeInfo() != null) {
                        return (A) fileJsonTypeInfo.jsonTypeInfo(); // this cast should be safe because we have checked the annotation class
                    }
                }
                if (ignoreJsonAnnotations(annoClass)) return null;
                return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annoClass);
            }
        };
    }

    private static <A extends Annotation> boolean ignoreJsonAnnotations(Class<A> annoClass) {
        if (annoClass == JsonSerialize.class) {
            return true;
        }
        if(annoClass == JsonDeserialize.class){
            return true;
        }
        if(annoClass == JsonIdentityReference.class){
            return true;
        }
        return annoClass == JsonIdentityInfo.class;
    }
}
```

My custom annotation is defined and described like this:

```
/**
 * This annotation inside of a annotation solution is a way to tell the importExportMapper how to serialize/deserialize
 * objects that already have a wrongly defined @JsonTypeInfo annotation (wrongly defined for the importExportMapper).
 *
 * Idea is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495480/how-to-properly-override-jacksonannotationintrospector-findannotation-to-replac
 */
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FileJsonTypeInfo {
    JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo();
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @JsonTypeInfo(defaultImpl = Customer.class, property = "", use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
    @TransferJsonTypeInfo(jsonTypeInfo = @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "customeridentifier"))
    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomerClientDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomerClientSerializer.class)
    private Customer customer;
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have two separate ObjectMapper instances configured for Server and Client.

**Server module:**

```
ObjectMapper serverMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(ServerDTO.class, new CustomerFileSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(ServerDTO.class, new CustomerFileDeserializer());
serverMapper.registerModule(module);

ServerDTO serverDto = serverMapper.readValue(jsonInput, ServerDTO.class);
String serialized = serverMapper.writeValueAsString(serverDto);
```

and

**Client module:**

```
ObjectMapper clientMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(ClientDTO.class, new CustomerClientSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(ClientDTO.class, new CustomerClientDeserializer());
clientMapper.registerModule(module);

ClientDTO clientDTO = clientMapper.readValue(jsonInput, ClientDTO.class);
String serialized = clientMapper.writeValueAsString(clientDTO);
```

Comment: As described in my answer your solution does not solve my problem. I defined those two `ObjectMapper`s as `@Bean`s in my spring context. I also told my import/export `ObjectMapper` which serializer/deserializer to use for which class. 

But the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations can only specify ONE serializer/deserializer.

Comment: I got an idea for a different solution: Have two identical `ObjectMapper` beans with different names and keep everything with one custom serializer/deserializer. Use one of them for import/export. Then put my logic in the serializer/deserializer. Is there a way to get the name of the `ObjectMapper` `@Bean` from within those methods? Namely the `serialize` method of `JsonSerializer` and the `deserializeObject` method of `JsonObjectDeserializer`.

Answer (score 1):

So I was trying to figure this out for the last few days. This is the progress I made so far:

I did two overrides for the default ObjectMapper in Spring and [made sure they are configured like the default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.spring-mvc.customize-jackson-objectmapper).

My custom mappers look like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper defaultV7ObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        // emulate the default settings as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper
        objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Customer.class, new CustomerClientSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Customer.class, new CustomerClientDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean("exportImportMapper")
    public ObjectMapper exportImportMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
                .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

        // emulate the default settings as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper
        objectMapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Customer.class, new CustomerFileSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Customer.class, new CustomerFileDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

I also removed the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations from my entities.

**HOWEVER there is one big difference with this change from annotations to adding the serializers via the module.**

- Let's say I have a class `A` that has a `Customer` property with the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.
- Let's also say I have a class `B` that has a `Customer` property without annotations.

By removing the annotations and setting the serializer/deserializer as shown above I have now added theses serializers/deserializers to **both** Customer properties. So it's not equivalent.

Or am I missing something here?